# MongoDB / mongoose split large documents

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

We are extending an existing node+mongo app. We need to add what could be large docs, but we currently do not know how big they could get to.

MongoDB has a default limit to 16mb max size, i am aware we can increase this but would rather not.

Has anyone ever seen a auto doc. split module? Something to auto split the docs into partials if the size exceeds a certain size?

Comment: How are your documents getting so large? Do they simply contain a lot of simple fields and subdocument fields, or do they contain long arrays?

Comment: Long arrays. We wanted to use Mongo as the app already uses mongo... but the new job is to store csv files of which we fear some of the csv files could be very large. The extra twist is we know the CSV files will be different.. the idea of automatically breaking the large documents up seemed the obvious first solution but not really finding any ways to do that yet.

Comment: Beware that the following statement is not correct : "MongoDB has a default limit to 16mb max size, i am aware we can increase this but would rather not.". Until version 3.6, MongoDB does not allow to alter this limit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have large CSV data to be stored in MongoDB, then there are two approaches which will both work well in different ways:

#### 1: Save in MongoDB format

This means that you have your application read the csv, and write it to a MongoDB collection one row at a time. So each row is saved as a separate document, perhaps something like this:

```json
{
  "filename" : "restaurants.csv",
  "version" : "2",
  "uploadDate" : ISODate("2017-06-15"),
  "name" : "Ace Cafe",
  "cuisine" : "British",
  etc
},
{
  "filename" : "restaurants.csv",
  "version" : "2",
  "uploadDate" : ISODate("2017-06-15"),
  "name" : "Bengal Tiger",
  "cuisine" : "Bangladeshi",
  etc
}
```

- This will take work on your application's part, to render the data into this format and deciding how and where to save the metadata
- You can index and query on the data, field by field and row by row
- You have no worries about any single document getting too large

#### 2: Save in CSV format using [GridFS](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/gridfs/)

This means that your file is uploaded as an un-analysed blob, and automatically divided into 16MB chunks in order to save it in MongoDB documents.

- This is easy to do, and does not disturb your original CSV structure
- However the data is opaque to MongoDB: you cannot scan it or read it row by row
- to work with the data, your application will have to download the entire file from MongoDB and work on it in memory

Hopefully one of these approaches will suit your needs.

Comment: I see, thanks that helps a lot. I did not know GridFS existed.